# Gbps to 2 100Mbps clients

Tags: gigabit-ethernet, gigabit

If I have a media server with a gigabit NIC connected to two 100Mbps xboxes on a gigabit switch, will both receive from it at 100Mbps or will one connection put the server's NIC in a 100Mbps mode and have an effective rate of 50Mbps to each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server's NIC is 1 Gb, the switch is 1 Gb, so the server's NIC will always be connected at 1 Gb. Best case, yes, each 100 Mb client can communicate at 100 Mb to the server. If the other subsystems in the server can keep up - CPU, disk IO, etc.